# Watching HD video on a new monitor with an old computer?

Tags: vga, hdvideo, graphics-card

I am looking into buying a new monitor (specifically, [this one](http://www.samsung.com/au/consumer/pc-peripherals/monitor/lcd-monitor/LS23CFVKF/XY/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=specification)). I am connecting it to an old computer (8 years old), that only has VGA output. I can connect it to the monitor as it is right now, but that's not good enough. I want to use the monitor's max resolution (1,920 x 1,080).

Here's my question: How can I watch HD videos on this monitor? should I buy a new video card? an external video card? a media streamer? What are my options here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 8-year old computer should manage 2 Mpx just fine for normal display operations (but since you don't give any specs it's impossible to be sure). However decompressing and playing HD video requires quite a bit of computing power, likely more than you have. It's a matter of CPU, graphics card, and perhaps motherboard components as well, so there may not be a single component you can just upgrade. You'll probably have to buy a special-purpose device, an [HTPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_theater_PC) (a special-purpose computer that can also serve as a general-purpose computer), or a new desktop or laptop computer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and imho best) solution would be to simply buy a [Sumvision MKV enclosure](http://www.sumvision.com.cn/searchResults.aspx?ptype=47) and cut out the computer completely.

It is capable of FULL 1080p HD, can play almost all/any format available and works very well.

Even if you manage to find a good AGP graphics card, the machine itself will most likely struggle in other areas being so old.